# How to evaluate an XACML Policy

Tags: authorization, access-control, policy, xacml, wso2-identity-server

Does anyone know the details about how to evaluate the XACML Policy?  Actually, I've written one policy like the following, but when I tried to evaluate with Trylt tool, it always failed with the "Indeterminate". This is my first time to write an XACML policy, I am not sure what's wrong with it? Could you do me a favor. Thanks a lot!

And I used Trylt tool like the following to evaluate my policy like the following:
Subject ="admin"

It always failed like:(It happends as well when using the sample policy on IS)
The error msg is "Indeterminate"

My environment is:
The version of IS is 4.1.0

Comment: Due to the limit of characters, I can not post my policy here. But I tried the sample policy on IS as well. It always failed with the error "Interminate". So, I guess maybe I missed some details of the policy evaluation process.

Answer (score 2):

When you created your policy's you enabled?
That error happens regularly when the IS can not associate the criteria provided in the tool Tray It with existing policies in the IS

I recommend reading the following blog

http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.mx/2013/06/try-out-xacml-policies-with-wso2.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it can be due to this [1]. New identity server has been release 4.5.0, i guess you could try out it.  This issue has been fixed on it [2]

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-1393. 
[2] http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/13/getting-start-with-wso2-identity-server-4-5-0/